# "apache http server has stopped working" while using PHP code on XAMPP server

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I'm trying to run a PHP script which the time run is around 10 minutes.
When I'm running the code on Chrome browser I get the following message after one minute:
"apache http server has stopped working"

My first guess is timeout problem..

so:

1) I have added the following lines into my code:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);
set_time_limit(0);
```

2) I have changed the php.ini file inside XAMPP directory to:

```
max_execution_time = 600
```

3) I have restarted the xampp apache & PHP

and still.. nothing.. Any idea?

Comment: Have you looked in you `php error log` or your `apache error log` or the `Windows Event Log`? Something in there should give you a clue.

Comment: I have same problem, apache error log: server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Comment: My problem resolved. The issue was a mistake in my PHP script code!